# Apply two sorting methods to one dataframe based on condition of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Where Col2 values are even, I want those rows sorted on Col2 & Col 3 ascending. Where Col2 values are odd, I want those rows sorted on Col2 ascending & Col3 Descending. Example below:

DF_original

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
 E      3       23
 D      2       10
 E      1      12
 E      2       18
 D      2       6
 E      1       21
 D      3       14
 D      3       9
```

Desired DF

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
 E       1       21
 E       1       12
 D       2        6
 D       2       10
 E       2       18
 E       3       23
 D       3       14
 D       3        9
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please add your effort, what did you already try. We're glad to help but we are not free work force.

Comment: `df.sort_values(['Col2','Col3'])`?

Comment: @QuangHoang it's not that simple

Comment: `df.sort_values(['Col2','Col3'], ascendint=[True, False])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to break up the dataframes into two parts and concatenate after sorting.

```
m = df['Col2'] % 2 == 0
d1=df[m].sort_values('Col3')
d2=df[~m].sort_values('Col3', ascending=False)
pd.concat([d1, d2]).sort_values('Col2')
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3
5    E     1    21
2    E     1    12
4    D     2     6
1    D     2    10
3    E     2    18
0    E     3    23
6    D     3    14
7    D     3     9
```

Similiar way without split and combining:

```
m = df['Col2'] % 2 == 0
df.assign(sortkey=df['Col3']*np.where(m,1,-1))\
  .sort_values(['Col2','sortkey']).drop('sortkey', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3
5    E     1    21
2    E     1    12
4    D     2     6
1    D     2    10
3    E     2    18
0    E     3    23
6    D     3    14
7    D     3     9
```

Comment: FWIW... I had better success with the second option. When I tried the first option the 'pd.concat([d1, d2]).sort_values('Col2')' resulted in col3 not being ordered properly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I not sure why that would be the case, however, the second is better anyway.  Happy coding!